# How can I distinguish scheme dialects in org-babel code blocks?

Tags: emacs, racket, org-mode

Evaluating this code (C-c C-c):

```
#+begin_src scheme
(andmap + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
#+end_src
```

leads to the following babel error:

```
ERROR: Unbound variable: andmap
```

The cause: babel evaluated the code with Guile instead of Racket.  How can I tell Babel to execute code using Racket, not Guile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://terohasu.net/blog/2011-09-08-on-racket-support-in-emacs-org-mode.html describes a way:

> When configuring Emacs to set things up I wasn’t familiar with Babel
>   or any of the solutions for evaluating Scheme code under Emacs for
>   that matter. After some looking at Babel and [Inferior
>   Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/External-Lisp.html),
>   I didn’t manage to configure Babel to invoke Racket for evaluating a
>   code listing. Instead I resorted to replacing the Babel code for
>   Scheme support (in the ob-scheme.el) with basically just the following
>   code:
>
> ```lisp
> (defun org-babel-execute:scheme (body params)
>   (let* ((tangle (cdr (assoc :tangle params)))
>          (script-file 
>           (if (string-equal tangle "no")
>               (org-babel-temp-file "org-babel-" ".rkt")
>             tangle)))
>     (with-temp-file script-file
>       (insert body))
>     (let* ((pn (org-babel-process-file-name script-file))
>            (cmd (format "racket -u %s" pn)))
>       (message cmd)
>       (shell-command-to-string cmd)
>       )))
> ```
>
> This solution creates a new Racket instance for every evaluation, and
>   hence is not as efficient as an Inferior Lisp based solution (or
>   similar), but it works, is more straightforward, avoids Racket issues
>   such as specifying the correct module context for evaluating the code,
>   and the evaluation context is always “clean” as a new Racket instance
>   is used.

Comment: Nowadays, ob-scheme uses geiser and can use guile, racket, chicken or mit-scheme (if I am not mistaken) for scheme evaluation: it depends on how you configure geiser.