# Use mit-scheme instead of guile for org-mode code block evaluation

Tags: emacs, scheme, org-mode, org-babel

I have a code block in org mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme
  (define (even? n)
    (= (remainder n 2) 0))

  (even? 3)
#+END_SRC
```

When I do C-c C-c to evaluate the code, I get the error '/bin/bash: guile: command not found'

I guess this is because org-babel expects that the scheme implementation installed is guile, but I have mit-scheme which I can run from the command line just by calling 'scheme'.

How do I get org-babel to use mit-scheme instead of trying to use guile?

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338255/how-can-i-distinguish-scheme-dialects-in-org-babel-code-blocks) doesn't solve my issue as the answer is very specific to racket.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `geiser-default-implementation` variable - that's used by `ob-scheme` package to evaluate Scheme code blocks...

Comment: If `ob-scheme` uses geiser, then it won't work with mit-scheme. Geiser only supports guile and racket.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a solution, but I gave up on trying to get org-mode code block evaluation working with mit-scheme and instead I just switch to scheme-mode when I want to evaluate my code and then do C-c C-e to evaluate each expression.

Answer (score 0):

Org-mode is not compatible with MIT-Scheme by default (the last time I checked it didn't work great with other Scheme either, for example try to evaluate the code returning `#t` or `#f`). But there is a workaround that makes it possible to make them work together with one culprit: the result will always be just a string-result (instead of, for example, table for list-of-lists result).

See the [blog-post](https://mobiusengineering.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/using-emacs-org-with-mit-scheme/) and [repository](https://bitbucket.org/mobius-eng/ob-scheme/overview) for how to set them up.